# Enum type argument not working

Tags: c#, enums

This may be a basic question, but I googled it and didn't find an answer. I hope you will help me. Consider I have an `enum` `ContactNumberType`:

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ContactNumberType))
```

If I use the above, the compiler gives no error, but when I write:

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(ContactNumberType)
```

It says:

> `ContactNumberType` is a type but used like a variable.

While the type of `ContactNumberType` is `Enum`, as far as I know, and the argument of method `GetNames` needs `EnumType`, so whats the issue with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `typeof` becuase the GetNames() method takes a parameter of type `Type`.  Keep in mind that providing a type name is not the same as an instance of `Type`, which is an object that contains the details of that type.

To pass a type as a parameter, you have two basic choices:

- Pass a `Type` instance
- Use a generic

The first of these (which many older methods such as `Enum.GetNames()` does) requires you to get a `Type` instance from the type identifier, which we can do using the `typeof()` operator.

The second of these allows you to pass a type name as a parameter to a method or class to make that method or class generic and tends to be used on newer methods (generics were introduced in .NET 2.0):

```
var items = someList.OfType<SomeTypeName>();
```

`Enum`, however, doesn't have a generic form of `GetNames()` that allows this, though you could create something like one:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static string[] GetNames<T>() where T : struct
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
    }
}
```

Which you could then call like:

```
string[] names = EnumHelper.GetNames<ContactNumberType>();
```

Answer (score 2):

`GetNames` takes a parameter of type `Type`. The issue is that `ContactNumberType` is not a `Type` object. When you use the `typeof` operator, it returns the appropriate `Type` object.

Answer (score 0):

Because `typeof` operator returns an object of `Type`